# Jquery: Can't select append element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, appendto

I am trying to display alert when I click the link inside the ul li but somehow it is not working. My jquery fail to select the link which I append it.

MY HTML

```
<ul id="typeList"></ul>
```

MY JQUERY

```
 $("a.type").on("click", function(){                
            alert("click");
 });

$("<li><a href='#' class='type' type =" +results.rows.item(i).Type + " >"+ results.rows.item(i).Type +"</a></li>").appendTo('ul#typeList');
```

DESIRED LINE CREATED

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="type" href='#' type ='People'>People</a></li>
   <li><a class="type" href='#' type ='Places'>Places</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `on` trigger to catch click events inside `ul`:

```
 $("#typeList").on("click", "a.type", function(){                
            alert("click");
 });
```

This attaches an event handler to only one element (your `ul#typeList`), but it will only work for `a.type` elements inside `ul`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Does that means I had to use if I using nested elements?

Comment: Not necessairly, but I recommend using it, because it attaches only one event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach an event handler to an element that does not yet exists!

Delegate the event to an element that does exist, like in the answer given by @des, or append the element before you attach the handler:

```
$("<li><a href='#' class='type' type =" +results.rows.item(i).Type + " >"+ results.rows.item(i).Type +"</a></li>").appendTo('ul#typeList');

$("a.type").on("click", function(){                
    alert("click");
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2f5kw/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this for getting the on click

```
$(function(){
   $(".type").click(function(){                
                alert("click");
     });
});
```

Comment: This is not correct. The problem is that dynamically elements cannot be selected for the events, because the handlers are attached on load. `.on()` works, but has to be added to a higher level at the DOM.

Comment: i have edited. now the jquery snippet loads after the page load is complete.